# Decay conditions on the Fourier coefficients ensuring that a smooth function doesn't vanish on some interval

Tags: fourier-analysis

**Let $f$ be a non-zero smooth $1$-periodic function. Is there a decay condition on its Fourier coefficients ensuring that it won't vanish identically on any interval?**

I mean a condition weaker than *"$c_n=O(e^{-r|n|})$ for some $r>0$"* ie. other than $f$ is analytic.

For example let

$$A_w=\left\{ \sum_{n\in \Bbb{Z}} c_n e^{2i\pi n x}, c_n\in \Bbb{C}, \forall k\ge 0, \lim_{|n|\to \infty} c_n n^k w_n=0\right\}, \qquad w_n=e^{\log^2 |n|}$$

Which is a ring. Will any non-zero function in $A_w$ vanish on some interval?

For $f,g$ smooth and $g(x_0)\ne 0$ then $fg=0$ implies that $f$ vanishes on $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$, so the condition is equivalent to $A_w$ being an integral domain.

Comment: You should take a look at Section 8.4 in Lars Hörmander ALPDO I. He has a wave-front-set approach to the regularity of Denjoy-Carleman classes. Since  the wave-front-set is defined via the Fourier transformation, it should have some links with your question.

Comment: Does quasi-analyticity translate into the kind of condition you're after? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-analytic_function (This is for Taylor series not Fourier series but there should be some way to move between the two)

Comment: I would look at $c_n=O(e^{-|n/\log |n||})$ and show that $f$ is in a quasi analytic class; by majorization, functions in $A_{w}$ are in a class that is not quasi analytic but that doesn't mean anything here; of course one always has the required property if $c_n$ is one-sided (eg $c_n =0, n < -N$) regardless of any decay properties except that $\sum_{n\ \ge -N} c_n e^{2i\pi n x}$ is the Fourier series of an integrable function

Comment: @conrad [There is an old book](https://1lib.fr/book/4986710/61150c?regionChanged=&redirect=255524490) in french (my language) which partially answers my question, giving sufficient conditions on the decay of the Fourier coefficients for $f$ being quasi analytic (all the derivatives vanish at one point is stronger than vanishing on some interval), on page 89 it gives the condition $|c_n|= O(e^{-p(n)})$ with $p'(t)t$ increasing to $\infty$ and $ \int_1^\infty \frac{p(t)}{t^2}dt=\infty$

Comment: "All the derivatives of $f$ vanish at $0$" and "$f$ vanish on some interval" might be almost the same in this context because for the former it means that its Fourier coefficients are $\hat{h}(n)$ with $h=f1_{x\in [0,1]}\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R})$, in which case $\sum_n e^{2i\pi nx} \hat{h}(n/N)$ vanishes on some interval for $N>1$.

Comment: great - will take a look at the book as I am good with French too; the condition makes sense since if $x_kp'(x_k)=k$ (first condition above has $x_k \to \infty$ with $k$) then the $k$ derivative is estimated roughly by the term $x_k^ke^{-p(x_k)}$ and the ratio of consecutive such (which must diverge) is comparable with $p'(k)/k$ and the divergence of that is equivalent by parts to the divergence of the integral above - $x/\log x$ was the first such function that came to my mind as one gets the series $1/(k \log k)$ which is divergent (and one wants $p(t)=o(t)$ to avoid analyticity)

Comment: "The Uncertainty principle in harmonic analysis" by Victor Havin and Burglind Jöricke is a book about this sort of questions.